# SAS Set a variable equal to another variable, rename it, and then merge

Tags: sas

I am trying to set the value of a variable to the value of another variable, then rename the original variable, then merge using the following code: (`MK_RETURN_DATA` is a subset of `RETURNOUTSET`. I just wanted merge the `MK_RETURN_DATA` with `RETURNOUTSET` with one variable in `MK_RETURN_DATA` renamed).

```
  data RETURNOUTSET;
    CUM_RETURN  = return_sec;
  run; 

  PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE MK_RETURN AS
      SELECT a.*
      FROM 
        RETURNOUTSET a
      WHERE a.SYMBOL = 'SPY';
  QUIT;

  DATA MK_RETURN_DATA;
    SET MK_RETURN;
    RENAME RETURN_SEC=MK_RETURN_RATE;
    DROP SYMBOL;
  RUN;

  proc sort data=MK_RETURN_DATA; by Date Time; run;
  proc sort data=RETURNOUTSET; by Date Time; run;

  data WITH_MARKET;
    merge RETURNOUTSET(IN=C) MK_RETURN_DATA(IN=D);
    by Date Time;
    if C;
  run;
```

However, I am getting very weird results in the first block of data with symbol "A" in `WITH_MARKET`. The value of `CUM_RETURN` is actually equal to the value of `MK_RETURN_RATE`, while I wanted it to be `return_sec`.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with dataset options.
First make sure the data is sorted.

```
proc sort data=RETURNOUTSET; by Date Time; run;
```

Then merge that dataset back with itself and use the appropriate KEEP, RENAME and WHERE dataset options to select the correct records to merge onto the original data.

```
data WITH_MARKET;
merge RETURNOUTSET(IN=C) 
      RETURNOUTSET(IN=D 
                   keep=symbol return_sec date time
                   rename=(symbol=x_symbol return_sec=MK_RETURN_RATE)
                   where=(x_symbol='SPY')
                  )
;
by Date Time;
if C;
drop x_symbol ;
run;
```

If you do not have SYMBOL='SPY' records for all of the DATE TIME values in your original data then the merge might not work. Or if you have multiple SYMBOL='SPY' records for the same DATE TIME values then you also might have trouble with this merge.

Comment: Shouldn't the where clause be where=(x_symbol='SPY') instead?

Comment: Yes. A useful thing to remember is that the dataset options are processes in alphabetical order. So KEEP before RENAME before WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

All of what you did up to this point is the same as this one datastep.  You put RETURN_SEC in CUM_RETURN, you filtered down to SYMBOL='SPY', and you renamed RETURN_SEC to MK_RETURN_RATE.

```
 DATA MK_RETURN_DATA;
    SET returnoutset(where=(symbol='SPY'));
    cum_return = return_sec;
    RENAME RETURN_SEC=MK_RETURN_RATE;
    DROP SYMBOL;
  RUN;
```

So ... CUM_RETURN equals MK_RETURN_RATE equals the former RETURN_SEC, as far as I can tell.  What were you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to use the subset of RETURNOUTSET (whose ticker symbol is the equal to "SPY") as a bench mark, and then merge this bench mark into RETURNOUTSET by time.

Comment: Okay, that's nice, but what are you trying to do with these variables?

Comment: There is a variable called return_sec in RETURNOUTSET. I want to rename this variable to MK_RETURN_RATE (only those with ticker 'SPY', i.e. the benchmark) and then merge the bench mark back to RETURNOUTSET. I want to run a regression on the RETURNOUTSET with the benchmark.

Comment: Okay, then it seems like you've done this.  Not sure where CUM_RETURN is coming into things.

Comment: I want to let CUM_RETURN equal to the sum of return_sec variable of the same stock symbol. (It basically stands for cumulative return). I was trying to do CUM_RETURN  = return_sec + lag(CUM_RETURN);, but it seems that there are issues with the Symbol A returns. So I let CUM_RETURN  = return_sec, then I discovered that CUM_RETURN is equal to MK_RETURN_RATE instead of return_sec in the Symbol A stock, while all stocks seems fine. This puzzles me ....